# how can I do to set the charset in meta tag automatically without having to manually add the value?

Tags: php, header, kohana

I am testing Kohana Framework and from what I read it automatically sets the charset when rendering the page:

> Request:: $ instance-> headers
>   ['Content-Type'] = 'text / html;
>   charset ='. Kohana:: $ charset;

how can I do to set the charset in meta tag automatically without having to manually add the value?

```
<html>
     <head>
         <title> title </title>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ***charset=utf-8***" />
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1> test </h1>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code untested:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(Kohana::$charset); ?>" />
```